# Is there any fast method to check whether a square matrix is symmetrical?

Tags: blas, scientific-computing, intel-mkl

I was wondering if is there any fast method to check whether a given square matrix is symmetrical.

I've checked some BLAS packages but don't seem to find anything. Using intel MKL the best method seems to be to call somatcopy, that performs an out-of-place matrix transposition of matrix A and stores the result on matrix B. It is then possible to check if matrix A is equal to B.

This method, however, requires an extra matrix to be stored in memory and I was looking for an approach with O(1) extra overhead.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: What do you mean by "fast"? *Any* method for an n x n  matrix will require O(n^2) comparisons. While the comparisons can be done in parallel, the implementation probably requires something equivalent (in terms of complexity) to an array copy.

Comment: @chepner, I'm looking for a single core solution (SIMD/AVX) is allowed. By fast I meant a cache-efficient algorithm (possibly using some cache-tilling technique).